# Handling Network Errors Python, Web Crawler

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, network-connection

I am making a web crawler on a large scale website. However, it always hit closed connections, SSL errors or other intermittent failures due to unstable connection.Thus I am finding a way to deal with this problem. This is my code below,can anyone tell me how to implement the wait or try again to start the project again when there is network connection

```
try:
     requests.get("http://example.com")
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
     pass  # handle the exception. maybe wait and try again later
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without trying to listen to the network interface itself, you can add a simple 'retry' mechanism when it fails:

```
import time

while True:
    try:
        requests.get("http://example.com")
        break  # you can also check the returned status before breaking the loop
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        time.sleep(300)  # wait 5 mins before retry
```